# Find a recursion (combinatorial)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Consider sequences that consist entirely of $ A$'s and $ B$'s and that have the property that every run of consecutive $ A$'s has even length, and every run of consecutive $ B$'s has odd length. Examples of such sequences are $ AA$, $ B$, and $ AABAA$, while $ BBAB$ is not such a sequence. How many such sequences have length 14?

Let $A(n)$ be the $n$-lettered sequences beginning with an $A$. Let $B(n)$ be the $n$-lettered sequences beginning with a $B$.

I am very confused how to set a recursion pattern.

$A$_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

There is one option to put an $A$. So: $A(n) = A(n-1)$.  But then we have:

$AA$_ _ _ _ _ _ _ Now there are two options, $A$ or $B$ but both with strings attached:  If $A$ is chosen, then the next one must be $A$, if $B$ is chosen then the next must be $BB$ or $A$.

It is very confusing what to do here?

**Hints and help only please!**

Comment: I like your start. If you begin with A, you must begin with AA but then any string of your type works.  If you begin with B then you must begin with $B^{2n+1}AA$ for some n, and then any string of your type works.  Good luck!

Comment: Note: Your formula $A(n)=A(n-1)$ is not correct.  For $n=2$, say, we have $A(2)=1$ but $A(1)=0$.

Comment: @amad27 Sorry, I missed the part about the Bs needing to be odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use functions $A(n), B(n)$ as defined in the question.

A string beginning with $A$ must be followed by a second $A$ and then by any valid string of length $n-2$ beginning with either $A$ or $B$.

A string beginning with $B$ must be either (i) followed by a second $B$ and then by any valid string of length $n-2$ beginning with $B$, so we keep an odd number of $B$s at the start, OR (ii) followed by any valid string of length $n-1$ beginning with $A$.

This results in the pair of recurrences:

$$A(n)=A(n-2) + B(n-2) \\
  B(n)=A(n-1) + B(n-2).$$

Comment: (+1): You might consider renaming the function F(n) , since the string has A's in it

Comment: @trueblueanil Good point. I've made the change. Thanks.

Comment: @MickA, (+1) but with $F(n-1)$ it is possible to have: $BBAA$ which is right for $F(n-1)$ but wrong overall (BB)?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Start with A is simple, for then we need to have another A, and we append a good string of length $n-2$.

Start with B is more complicated. (i) If we  have an A next, then we need another, then a good string of length $n-3$.
(ii) If we have a B next, then $\dots$.

**Added:** We expand on the hint. Let $F(n)$ be the number of good strings of length $n$. There are $F(n-2)$ good strings of length $n$ that begin with A. For good strings of length $n$ that begin with B, they start with BAA, or BBBAA, or BBBBBAA, and so on, with a good string of the appropriate length appended,  That gives a count of $F(n-3)+F(n-5)+F(n-7)+\cdots$. This gives the recurrence
$$F(n)=F(n-2)+F(n-3)+F(n-5)+F(n-7)+\cdots.$$
Now we work our way up to $14$.

Comment: So $A(n) = A(n-1)$ is correct? (+1)

Comment: No, it is not correct.  If $n=2$ say, $A(2) = 1$ but $A(1)=0$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, how do you work directly with $F(n)$ though?

Comment: @AndréNicolas, for $B$ beginning, why is it: $F(n-3)$? Why cant we just consider: 

$B$_ _ _ _ .. So we have $F(n-1)$ for $B$?

Comment: Okay so I got the final recurrence to be $F(n) = F(n-2) + 2F(n-3)$?

Comment: @AndréNicolas, thanks, I'm a bit confused though. To get your nice recurrence, what did you do? You only considered two cases right? $AA$ and $BBB$? How did you get this recurrence then?

Comment: @AndréNicolas, this doesnt seem right. If you have: $BBB$ then $F(n-3)$ it is possible to get: $BBB BAA$? Which is wrong?

Comment: Hi @AndréNicolas - Two points I'm unclear on: 1. On your last comment: "If after the $B$ there comes another $B$ (so two $B$'s at the start, not three) then again anything goes, giving $F(n−2)$." - what if the "anything goes" begins with $A$? Don't we end up with an ill-formed string because it begins with an even number of $B$s? 2. In your answer: "For good strings of length $n$ that begin with $B$, they start with $BAA$, or $BBBAA$, or $BBBBBAA$, and so on..." - does this count the string of all $B$s where $n$ is odd?

Comment: Yes, there is a mistake there. But the "long" recurrence still works. I will withdraw the short one, and try to fix the idea.

Comment: The recurrences of Mick A are now correct and should be accepted.